# Treeview in javascript

Tags: javascript, search, tree, treeview

I need to make something similar to treeview.  It doesn't need collapsing it just needs to show some heirachy, but in a table view.

Flat data comes in from a database.  I unflattened it and made a tree, but now that it's a tree, I wanted to turn it back into an array, so I can easily iterate using a for loop.

After looking at the source code of other treeviews my method was going to be like this:

1. From flat data from a db, unflatten:

   ```
   [
       { id: 1, name: 'node1', parentId: 0 },
       { id: 2, name: 'node2', parentId: 1 },
       { id: 4, name: 'node4', parentId: 2 },
       { id: 5, name: 'node5', parentId: 2 },
       { id: 6, name: 'node6', parentId: 3 },
       { id: 3, name: 'node3', parentId: 1 },
   ]
   ```
2. The tree is now ordered and has a hierarchy (levels for indentation). Traverse the tree.  I add level and children.

   ```
   [
       id: 1,
       name: 'node1',
       level: 0,
       children: [
           { 
               id: 2, 
               name: 'node2', 
               parentId: 1,
               level: 1
               children: [
                   { 
                       id: 4, 
                       name: 'node4', 
                       parentId: 2,
                       level: 2,
                       children: []
                   },
                   { 
                       id: 5, 
                       name: 'node5', 
                       parentId: 2,
                       children: []
                   },
               ]
           },
           { 
               id: 3, 
               name: 'node1', 
               parentId: 1,
               children: [
                   { 
                       id: 6, 
                       name: 'node6', 
                       parentId: 3,
                       children: []
                   },
               ]
           },
       ]
   ]
   ```

   3. Compress it back into an array form with order, level.

      ```
      [
          { id: 1, name: 'node1', level: 0, parentId: 0, children: [...] },
          { id: 2, name: 'node2', level: 1, parentId: 1, children: [...] },
          { id: 4, name: 'node4', level: 2, parentId: 2, children: [...] },
          { id: 5, name: 'node5', level: 2, parentId: 2, children: [...] },
          { id: 3, name: 'node3', level: 1, parentId: 1, children: [...] },
          { id: 6, name: 'node6', level: 2, parentId: 3, children: [...] },

      ]
      ```

Of which I can easily create a table from.

I've gotten close with the following code:

```
var data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'node1', parentId: 0 },
    { id: 2, name: 'node2', parentId: 1 },
    { id: 4, name: 'node4', parentId: 2 },
    { id: 5, name: 'node5', parentId: 2 },
    { id: 6, name: 'node6', parentId: 3 },
    { id: 3, name: 'node3', parentId: 1 }
]

function unflatten (arr, parentId, level) {
  let output = []
  for (const obj of arr) {
    if (obj.parentId === parentId) {
      var children = unflatten(arr, obj.id, level+1)
            obj.level = level

      if (children.length) {

        obj.children = children
      }
      output.push(obj)
    }
  }
  // console.log(output)
  return output
}

function flatten (tree) {
    var output = []
    for(const node of tree) {
    if(node.children !== undefined){
        var nodeChildren = flatten(node.children.reverse())

        for(const child of nodeChildren){
                output.push(child)
        }
      }
        output.push(node)
  }
  return output
}

var dataCopy = Object.assign([], data)
console.log('data', dataCopy)

var res = unflatten(data, 0, 0)
console.log('tree', res)

var resCopy = Object.assign([], res)

var res2 = flatten(resCopy)
console.log('reflatten', res2)
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ctd09r85/10/

That fiddle is the closest I've gotten, but it's a bit reversed and out of order.

How can I do this, and is this a reasonable way to build the tree view.

Comment: do you want only the result of `3`? what is the content of `children` in the objects?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by result of `3`, but the children was just children underneath the node. Doesn't have to be there, but can be.

Comment: i mean the result of the third point above: *"Compress it back into an array ..."*

Comment: Yup, that's correct

Comment: but what is in children?

Comment: @NinaScholz children would be the subnode underneath in the tree, if that makes sense.  For my output, I was pushing the object and everything blew as I was traversing.  So, for instance, the compressed object with the `id: 3` was

Comment: ` { 
                id: 3, 
                name: 'node1', 
                parentId: 1,
                level: 1
                children: [
                    { 
                        id: 6, 
                        name: 'node6', 
                        parentId: 3,
                        level: 2,
                        children: []
                    },
                 ]
        },` @NinaScholz